# Does RTSP live streaming just not work on Android 1.5/1.6?

Tags: android, rtsp

My main dev phone is a Nexus 1 running 2.2. I have successfully been streaming live video to this device from a Wowza server for several weeks now.

I have now taken my application (without modifications) and put it on a Sony Ericsson Xperia running 1.6. The video will not play. I get the following errors:

```
MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
...
MediaPlayer: info/warning (1/26)
PlayerDriver: Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
MediaPlayer: Error:(1,-1)
VideoView: Error: 1,-1
```

I've been googling around, but just can't seem to get a clear answer. Does anyone know if live streaming just doesn't work on some versions of Android?

Comment: Can you please share Project link u have done on Live Streaming.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Sam, sorry the application in question was one I did for work, and I do not have source code available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used RTSP Live streaming on 1.5, 1.6, and 2.1; so you should be able to get this to work; but you may have an encoding that only works on 2.2.  What type of stream are you streaming?

Comment: I have a number of different streams coming in that all eventually get converted to H264 through some voodoo from another coder. I'm not in control of the streams, so I don't always know all the details on that side of things. It is though, a great comfort to me to hear that someone else has gotten it working. The documentation out there can get pretty patchy, and I couldn't find a definitive statement that it could be done.

You get best answer for the pat on the head I needed. Now if only I could find out what the dang error numbers mean.

Answer (score 1):

video stream for android:

```
package com.test.videodemo;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView; 

public class videodemo extends Activity {

VideoView v1;
String path;
Uri url;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
    videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    setContentView(videoHolder);

    videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://bitcast-in.bitgravity.com/web18/web18/3gp/indo_china_suhasini.3gp"));
    videoHolder.requestFocus();
    videoHolder.start(); 

}
```

}

Comment: does youtube video rtsp link works in any of android version ?. i am not able to play single video.i used http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ api to get the rtsp url.